# Chrome extension icons not all showing

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I followed the instructions for manifest icons provided by Google from their developer website.

Here's a snippet of my manifest file (the png images are squared and the correct size):

```
"icons": { 

    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
```

So I uploaded my app and then installed it, but for some reason my app logo is still not showing on the chrome://extensions page.

[image]

Also in the chrome webstore my logo is not filling the whole space of the puzzle piece as seen here:

[image]

Is there something else I need to do for it to show?

Comment: Two things to check: first, make sure you restart chrome.  You shouldn't have to but it seems to fix this sometimes.  second, make sure the icons are in the right path as well as name.

Comment: @Brian Done that, didn't work.

Comment: Zip the icons and upload somewhere, post the link here, please. BTW, you have an *extension* for which webstore always shows a small logo inside the puzzle piece.

Comment: @wOxxOm here are the [icons](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5JRU3pcUj0AN21mVnRSTm9ZTGs/view?usp=sharing). Thanks for that info about extensions, I looked at webstore again and understood what you were saying

Comment: No problems here: the 48px icon is showing on the extensions page if I put it into another extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you show your manifest and a screenshot of this? I've updated the question to show the full manifest file. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't see the full manifest in your question. Here's [mine](https://puu.sh/jdKJR/4ccf5fca76.txt) and the [pic](https://puu.sh/jdKFA/f4c168b37d.png).

Answer (score 9):

I found my problem in the manifest file.

Originally I had my "icons" object inside the "browser_action" object like this:

```js
"browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": { 
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    }, 
    "default_icon": "icon128.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
```

Upon relocating the "icons" object out of the "browser_action" object,
the icon showed up in the chrome://extensions page like it is suppose to.

```js
"icons": { 
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "default_icon": "icon128.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
```

Comment: Awesome!  Had the same issue,  thanks for the solution!